# AngularJS custom event directive does not update layout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

### AngularJS $scope.$eval do not update layout

I am using AngularJs $scope.$eval to dynamically execute function. It is found the $scope value is update while the layout do not update.

```
    testApp.directive("click", function(){
        return {
            link: function($scope, $element, $attr){
                $element.bind("click", function(event){
                    $scope.$eval($attr.click);
                })
            }
        };
    }); 

    testApp.controller('TestController', function TestController($scope) {
        $scope.add = function(){
            $scope.filteredData = [
            {
                'name' : 'name 1',
                'value' : 'value 1'
            }, 
            {
                'name' : 'name 2',
                'value' : 'value 2'
            }
           ];
            $scope.filteredData.push(
                {
                    'name' : 'name 2',
                    'value' : 'value 2'
                }
            );
        };
    });
```

If I tried to add $scope.$apply(). The layout would update according to $scope value.

```
    testApp.directive("click", function(){
        return {
            link: function($scope, $element, $attr){
                $element.bind("click", function(event){
                    $scope.$eval($attr.click);
                    $scope.$apply();
                })
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$apply`:

```
testApp.directive("click", function(){
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr){
            element.on("click", function(event){
                scope.$eval(attr.click);
                scope.$apply();
            })
        }
    };
});
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc... You can also use `$apply()` to enter the AngularJS execution context from JavaScript.

Keep in mind that in most places (controllers, services) $apply has already been called for you by the directive which is handling the event. An explicit call to `$apply` is needed only when implementing custom event callbacks, or when working with third-party library callbacks.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - 
Integration with the browser event loop](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#integration-with-the-browser-event-loop).

[image]

Comment: Then mean if I bind native event and use $scope.$eval, I need to use $scope.$apply() at the end of the event handler. Isn't it?